# svg from slicer program to be scaled

Tags: svg, xhtml

I wish to centre an SVG embedded in an xhtml file generated by the digital printing slic3r program. I split up the multiple layers into individual files (shown below). When I try to use viewbox or translate or scale, I just can't get it to move at all. I don't want to adjust the points on the individual elements `<g>` because that could get very messy. Can anyone find what code to add that will genuinely center and scale the svg?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head></head>
<body bgcolor = "#000000">
<svg width="300px" height="163.75px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:slic3r="http://slic3r.org/namespaces/slic3r">    <g id="layer1" slic3r:z="1.5e-007">    <polygon slic3r:type="contour" points="300,163.75 0,163.75 0,0 300,0" style="fill: white" />  </g></svg></body></html>
```

Comment: Where are you adding the viewBox, translate or scale?

Comment: If I add transform="translate(100 50)"  after <g id="layer1" I can move the x,y start coordinates but the objects width and height are truncated. I can try to add "viewbox" after "<svg width="300px" height="163.75px" " but that gives whacky results or does nothing..does not seem to react to spec?

Comment: It is unclear what you are after.  Your title says you want it "scaled". Later you want to "center and scale". Center and scale where? On the page?  In the SVG?  Centre horizontally, vertically or both?  Please add more information.

Comment: Basically the issue is that I was using IE11. SVG handling is pathetic. The solution was to use Safari, then it was possible to scale the SVG. The eventual solution was to render to Bitmap then display it traditionally after scaling before rendering.